# php artisan won't execute because of heroku config

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, heroku

My Laravel 4.2 app uses PostgreSQL on Heroku. Yesterday a weird problem appear when `php artisan` command won't execute. It threw the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "type": "ErrorException",
        "message": "Undefined index: host",
        "file": "\/project-name\/app\/config\/database.php",
        "line": 5
    }
}
```

But based on [Matt Staufer's tutorial here](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-on-heroku-using-a-postgresql-database), that line contains the config variable for Heroku's DB connection. If I comment out those config variables, I can run `php artisan` in my local machine.

Nonetheless, today the problem got weirder. I got an SQLSTATE[08006]7 error on Heroku after I `push` my changes, which from what I read is related to `localhost` pointing to IPv4 instead of IPv6. So I tried to do what a noob will do, destroy the DB and create a new one on Heroku. And now I got an error when try to `migrate` via Heroku CLI.

```
{
    "error": {
        "type": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
        "message": "Call to undefined function Symfony\\Component\\Console\\mb_convert_variables()",
        "file": "\/app\/vendor\/symfony\/console\/Symfony\/Component\/Console\/Application.php",
        "line": 1154
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what is wrong with my app and my Heroku config?

Thanks

---

**Update**

Based on a discussion with a friend, the first error message was because the config variable set by Heroku could not be accessed in local environment.

Comment: And the second error??

Comment: @sergiovilar I am not sure why, but seems like a conflict in composer packages. The error disappeared when I re-clone the repo and reinstall the composer.